# Sorting a list using a regex in Python

Tags: python, lambda

I have a list of email addresses with the following format:

name###@email.com

But the number is not always present.  For example: john45@email.com, bob@email.com joe2@email.com, etc.  I want to sort these names by the number, with those without a number coming first.  I have come up with something that works, but being new to Python, I'm curious as to whether there's a better way of doing it.  Here is my solution:

```
import re

def sortKey(name):
    m = re.search(r'(\d+)@', name)
    return int(m.expand(r'\1')) if m is not None else 0

names = [ ... a list of emails ... ]
for name in sorted(names, key = sortKey):
    print name
```

This is the only time in my script that I am ever using "sortKey", so I would prefer it to be a lambda function, but I'm not sure how to do that.  I know this will work:

```
for name in sorted(names, key = lambda n: int(re.search(r'(\d+)@', n).expand(r'\1')) if re.search(r'(\d+)@', n) is not None else 0):
    print name
```

But I don't think I should need to call re.search twice to do this.  What is the most elegant way of doing this in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better using `re.findall` as if no numbers are found, then it returns an empty list which will sort before a populated list. The key used to sort is any numbers found (converted to ints), followed by the string itself...

```
emails = 'john45@email.com bob@email.com joe2@email.com'.split()

import re
print sorted(emails, key=lambda L: (map(int, re.findall('(\d+)@', L)), L))
# ['bob@email.com', 'joe2@email.com', 'john45@email.com']
```

And using `john1` instead the output is: `['bob@email.com', 'john1@email.com', 'joe2@email.com']` which shows that although lexicographically after joe, the number has been taken into account first shifting `john` ahead.

There is a somewhat hackish way if you wanted to keep your existing method of using re.search in a one-liner (but yuck):

```
getattr(re.search('(\d+)@', s), 'groups', lambda: ('0',))()
```